# Как переписать код php чтобы ссылка не индексировалась поисковиками?

Tags: php

```
<?
function get_stat( $url, $headers )
{
    $handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $response = curl_exec( $handle );
    $code = curl_getinfo( $handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
    return array( "code" => $code, "response" => $response );
}

$url_yandex_disk = "https://yadi.sk/d/swF1ayi8DGM2aQ";

$result = get_stat( "https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk/public/resources/download?public_key=" . urlencode( $url_yandex_disk ), array());
if( $result["code"] == 200 )
{
  $result["response"] = json_decode( $result["response"], true );
  echo '<a class="button10" href="' . $result["response"]["href"] . '">Скачать</a> Скачать оба варианта с Яндекс диска в одном архиве';
}
else
{
  echo "error";
}
?>
```

Comment: вроде бы надо дописать `<a href="url" rel="nofollow"  >ytext</a>`

Comment: Нет это все равно будет видно поисковикам Давно уже не актуально. Спам ссылочный еще больше почему то набирается в процентах. Надо что то типо этого :        <a href="javascript:goPage('https://www.bluestacks.com/')" class="button10" target="_blank">Скачать</a> <script>function goPage(sPage) {
    window.location.href = sPage;
}</script>

Comment: ну или может ещё от yandex понт типа `<!-- noindex -->здесь ссылка<!--/ noindex -->`.

Comment: Нет это все не то Все старо Надо ссылку саму коверкать добавлять в нее типо как на JS я показал А это ноfollow noindex не работает понт

Comment: Nofollow noindex это все понт Я показал как на JS это делается а как php это реализовать ?

Comment: ну дак и сделайте на js в чем проблема то? пхп вам тут особо ничем не поможет. и не обобщайте поисковики с прочими ботами.

Comment: С ками прочими ботами ? Яндекс бот есть что тут обобщенного Что за интриги вы тут плетете ?

Comment: На JS такое не реализовать, чтобы на прямую скачивалось с Яндекс диска

Comment: Вот как заставить или слить в одно этот JS        <a href="javascript:goPage('http://www.info-lan.ru')" class="button10" target="_blank">Перейти</a> <script>function goPage(sPage) {
    window.location.href = sPage;
}</script>  и этот PHP выше? Даже пусть это будет на любом одном языке PHP или JS но чтобы суть то что они делают или выполняют было в одном коде. ?

Comment: Добавьте обычный echo в PHP коде чтобы вывел в страницу код Javascript для функции goPage и добавьте собственный код для ссылки.

Comment: php - выполняется на сервере, JavaScript на клиенте. И чтобы "слить" несливаемое вам необходимо добавить код JS, как подсказывает @Daniel Protopopov

Comment: @Helpsetup чего то не понял почему на js не реализовать? Вы же можете вставить, на худой конец, кусок js. Типа:
`echo '<a class="button10" onclick="window.open(\'' . $result["response"]["href"] . '\', \'_blank\')">Скачать</a>';`

Comment: Так и осталось непонятно, чем не угодил nofollow, так что проголосовал (проголосую) за закрытие вопроса. // Для справки: гугл умеет обрабатывать js.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите, чтобы поисковик не переходил по ссылке «скачать», то добавьте к ней атрибут nofollow:

```
echo '<a class="button10" href="' . $result["response"]["href"] . '">Скачать</a> Скачать оба варианта с Яндекс диска в одном архиве';
```

---

Но лучше запретить индексацию всей страницы. Самые простые способы это сделать:

- Добавить на страницу meta-тег: `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`
  или
- Добавить к ответу http-заголовок: `header('X-Robots-Tag: noindex');`

Comment: Нет это не то не ноиндекс не нофоллов именно как я написал надо. Это все я знаю и это мне не как не годится. не буду рассказывать почему, так в двух словах надо хорошие показатели сайта. Был опыт закрывал как вы говорили, да для поисковиков это работает для бирж нет !

Comment: Нужно эти два кода вместе на одном языке можно но чтобы действия которые они выполняют в одном были

Answer (score 0):

Два варианта, первый защита от парса href, второй с защитой от парса по маскам "http://*". Двигаясь в этом направлении легко написать защиту от 99% парсеров, например добавляя/убирая левые символы в ссылки.

```
<a url="http://google.com" onclick="location.href=this.getAttribute('url');">link 1</a>

<a url="google.com" onclick="location.href='http://'+this.getAttribute('url');">link 2</a>
```

Ну и в коде php

```
echo '<a class="button10" url="' . $result["response"]["href"] . '" onclick="location.href=this.getAttribute(\'url\');">Скачать</a> Скачать оба варианта с Яндекс диска в одном архиве';
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте форму:

```
<form action="http://example.com/download.php">
    <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.submit()">Скачать</a>
</form>
```

PHP код в вашем случае без использования шаблонизатора будет такой:

```
echo '<form action="' . $result["response"]["href"] . '"><a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.submit()">Скачать</a></form>
```